# go easy on... and go overboard with

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms, antonyms

I'm looking for synonymous and antonymous expressions of "go easy on spices" and "go overboard with spices." Can you think of others?

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/go%20easy%20on + http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/overuse?s=ts

Comment: the online thesaurus lists a lot of words that might not fit the context.

Comment: Are you asking about "hot" spices that can make a person cry (such as black pepper, chili peppers, and ginger)?  Or other kinds of spices?  Or both?

Comment: What does it matter what kinds of spices I'm talking about?

Comment: The kinds of spices matter, because some spice-related metaphors refer to "heat", "burning", "fires", "crying", "sneezing", and related phenomena.

Comment: To simplify things, just assume I'm talking about salt or sugar.

Answer (score 4):

> Go easy on spices
>
> - use spices sparingly
> - keeping it mild/bland

---

> Go overboard with spices
>
> - season it heavily
> - spice it up
> - go mad with the spices
> - spice the hell out of it
> - spice it liberally

Comment: Are there more colloquial alternatives, like overdo?

Comment: I would need context. Overdo is to me more negative than going overboard. overboard is more "funny" and overdo is more of a negative criticism in my ears. You cannot ask someone to overdo something, but you can ask them to go overboard

Answer (score 1):

To mplungjan's list I would add

> Don't go hog-wild with the(m) spices.

and

> They like it hot. Spice it up to beat the band.

Comment: Are there any similar expressions involving "free"?

Comment: Not in the "colloquial" register you've asked for.  *Don't be too free with those spices*.

Comment: I seem to have seen expressions like "free hand." Can it be used?

Comment: "with a free hand" means to do something liberally.   He poured the Scotch with a free hand.

Comment: Does that mean we can say "the cook uses spices with a free hand" to mean he uses lots of spices, perhaps too much?

Comment: I suppose you could use it with spices.  But I don't think it would be quite idiomatic in an imperative construction:  Don't use a free hand with the spices.

Comment: And "uses spices with a free hand" probably not, but "The cook spiced the dish with a rather free hand" would be ok.   It describes a physically liberal manner of doing something. The glass of Scotch has rather a lot of Scotch in it, and the Scotch wasn't delicately poured. Those are the connotations. The verb "use" seems too abstract for it.

Comment: What about "sprinkle the salt with a free hand"? Is that concrete enough?

Comment: Be aware that depending on context, that could mean "with a hand that wasn't busy" ... *liberally sprinkle with salt* is more idiomatic.

Comment: @Apollyon: actually, **sprinkle** and **with a free hand** tend to suggest opposite things.  It would be better to say *He salted the soup with a rather free hand.*

Comment: Opposite things? If so, wouldn't "sprinkle" and "liberally" also suggest opposite things?

Comment: @Apollyon: I have not used the two words, sprinkle and liberal, together here. But the phrases "a liberal sprinkling" or "sprinkle liberally" are indeed somewhat contradictory.  If I were told to give something a liberal sprinkle of something (chopped nuts, water, powdered sugar, whatever) I would understand that instruction to mean "feel free to use quite a lot more than the word 'sprinkle' suggests".  **sprinkle** then becomes only the manner of dispersion, when usually it suggests both manner of dispersion and the (relatively small) quantity dispersed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest simply **don't over-season**, versus **... and don't skimp on the seasoning**. There are so many synonyms for “don't overdo ...” and “be generous with ...” that it's impossible to list them all (now someone will try).

For salt and sugar, “go easy on” is probably just about the most universally understood expression to use. No need to try too hard :o)

For practical examples, I'd suggest perhaps checking out some TV chefs / recipe books for what's considered normal (by them). Just don't treat Lloyd Grossman as an authority, he talks very oddly. Being British, I'm thinking of Nigella, Delia Smith, Anthony Worrall Thompson, Ainsley Harriott, ...